# Auth::guard login for only the current request?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm looking into an "authenticated URL" type middleware for my Laravel application where a token is generated and that token relates to an authenticated user ID and the hash of a single URL. In other words, a way of viewing a session page from an e-mail without being initially signed-in, using a high-entropy token.

When the user visits the URL, for example `https://www.example.com/some/url?authtoken=WDu4UQ5SQr4WGlfMYErxRy3hjdFMs02f2NqbQ7PA`, the `AuthenticatedUrl` middleware looks up the `authtoken` in the database, verifies the hash of the request's URL and the stored URL match, then logs in the appropriate user ID (`Auth::guard('user')->login($token->getUser())`) so the page's controller can respond as normal.

That being said, I would prefer to only allow this middleware to authenticate the request itself, not the entire session. Is this possible without causing issues with an existing normal Laravel session?

Comment: I think it's quite difficult to use session feature using token based approach. You have to make fully api based development for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the `Guard::onceUsingId($id)` function which does exactly this. It logs in the request without setting any related session values or cookies.